# Eclipse: Associating editors with natureId

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

Is it possible to associate an editor with project natureId? I have a project, which contains files with different file extensions, but they get edited with the same editor.

I have tried to match the content-type with the natureId and editor by leaving the Extension type empty.. Unfortunately it doesn't work or I'm not doing it right :(

Overriding the default editor for a project would also work, if that's possible!?

What I've tried so far:

```
  <extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
 <content-type
       describer="test.FOPContentDescriber"
       id="test.content.type"
       name="FO Files"
       priority="high">
 </content-type>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        class="test.editors.FOEditor"
        contributorClass="test.editors.FOEditorContributor"
        default="false"
        icon="icons/fo_editor_16.png"
        id="test.editors.FOEditor"
        name="%editor.name">
     <contentTypeBinding
           contentTypeId="test.content.type">
     </contentTypeBinding>
  </editor>
```

The content describer class:

```
package test.fop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.QualifiedName;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.IContentDescriber;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.IContentDescription;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.ITextContentDescriber;


public class FOPContentDescriber implements IContentDescriber {

    public FOPContentDescriber() {
        System.out.println("init content describer");
    }

    @Override
    public int describe(InputStream contents, IContentDescription description) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Call describer");
        return ITextContentDescriber.VALID;
    }

    @Override
    public QualifiedName[] getSupportedOptions() {
        return IContentDescription.ALL;
    }

}
```

Comment: The editor to use is determined by the file content type or the extension if no content type is defined. There is no default editor for a project.

Comment: Every file contains a format that I can recognize... Is there an extension point for file content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define file content types using the `org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes` extension point.

You can use the `describer` element of the content type definition to specify a class which implements `IContentDescriber`. This class will called to check if a file is valid for the content type. The describer can also extract information from the file and store it in the content description.

Note: the content describer is only given on input stream, there is no way to find out the file path.

When you define an editor with the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point you can use a `contentTypeBinding` element to bind the editor to content types.

Comment: I've tried to do the same. See my edit above... The class FOEditorDescriber doesn't get called at all and I don't understand why.

Comment: I think you need to specify the `file-extensions` attribute for `content-type`, it won't just try the describer on everything.

Comment: I've tried it also with file-extension, but it doesn't work... The problem is that I want to recognize the editor by content, not by file extension, because the file extension is unfortunately random.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right.. It calls the describer, if the file-extension is set.